# Android Splash screen to activity

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app and when I go to debug it on my samsung galaxy the Splash activity loads first,as it should, but after that the app crashes/stops right after doing the "Splash" activity. It doesn't go to the "MainActivity" activity after the thread sleeps for 5 seconds. Does anyone know what might be causing the problem? Plus after I tried debugging the app and loaded it onto my phone the app isn't even showing up. I am using Eclipse by the way. It shows the app in my application manager on my phone but it doesn't show the icon in my app screen.

Here is my Splash.java:

```
package com.example.mihirsandroidapp;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMainActivity =  new Intent("com.example.mihirandroidsapp.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}


}
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/cartooncat"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mihirsandroidapp.SPLASH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mihirsandroidapp.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here is my main activity which should start after the splash screen:

```
package com.example.mihirsandroidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter += 1;
            display.setText("Total is " + counter);


        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter -= 1;
            display.setText("Total is " + counter);

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: @mihirb Programmers.SE is about the design, architecture, algorithms and patterns side of programming (see the [help/on-topic]).  Stack Overflow is for the debugging and implementation questions (which you appear to have here).

Comment: first, please post the exact exception your getting from your logcat output.  Second, there's really no need to use a string based intent if you're opening an activity in your own application.  THere's a version of the Intent constructor which takes a Class<?> instance, and you should use that internal to your app.

Comment: Why are you making users wait five seconds looking at a crappy Splash Screen they don't care about when they could be using your app?

Comment: @mibirb a piece of advice about Splash Screens on Android. Users don't like them. Many people on this forum don't like them. And The Great Google doesn't like them. They are not recommended. Plus they don't work very well with the Android architecture & life-cycle. This is not iOS.

Comment: There is no easy way to make a good splash screen on Android, e.g. one that entertains the user _while_ a heavy startup operation is ongoing. Most examples, like the one here, are just delaying the main activity by showing a splash activity for a few seconds.

Comment: i have made a splash using this approch https://github.com/meetmehdi/GoodSplash

Answer (score 15):

Oh.. Where do I start.. Let's go through all of the issues:

1) Fix your manifest. Definitely not the right way to declare your activities. Here is what it should look like:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/cartooncat"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

2) Now let's fix the way you start your activity:

```
Intent openMainActivity =  new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
```

3) Don't call `finish()` in `onPause()` - you break native activity lifecycle flow. Call `finish()` right after you start new activity:

```
Intent openMainActivity =  new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openMainActivity);
finish();
```

4) Instead of creating separate thread, just a create a Handler and post `Runnable` there with 5 seconds delay:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //this will be called after 5 seconds delay
    }
}, 5000);
```

Here is entire file put together:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent openMainActivity =  new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(openMainActivity);
            finish();

        }
    }, 5000);    
}
```

If it doesn't help - we definitely need to look at logcat output...

Comment: "Oh.. Where do I start.." +1 for that comment. But also cos this is a good answer and covers all the bases.

Comment: It helped me to understand Splash screen. Thank you Pavel.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this if one is ready to compromise on drawing performance is to define custom theme with splash image that one wants to use as window background and use this custom theme as application theme

styles.xml

```
 <resources>
        <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_image</item>
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <application
        android:debuggable="true"        
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        ...
</application>
```

This would use the @drawable/background_image as the window.background. As a result if the activities has transparent background then @drawable/background_image will be visible as activities background. One can avoid this by setting appropriate color or drawable in onCreate of every activity programatically as

```
public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layoutResID);
activity.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.window_bg);

}
```

[Check this for more information](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html)

Answer (score 1):

All what you need for a splash screen

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_DURATION = 1000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_DURATION);
}}
```

In drawables create this **bg_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@color/app_color"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_in_app_logo_big"/>
</item></layer-list>
```

In **styles.xml** create a custom theme

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
</style>
```

and finally in **AndroidManifest.xml** specify the theme to your activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {            /*create a new thread */
                              @Override
                              public void run() { /*
                                                                  * The purpose of this thread is to
                                                                  * navigate from one class to another
                                                                  * after some time
                                                                  */

                                     try {
                                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            /*
                                             * We are creating this new thread because we don’t
                                             * want our main thread to stop working for that
                                             * time as our android stop working and some time
                                             * application will crashes
                                             */
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                     }
                                     finally {
                                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                                          Splash_Class.class);
                                            startActivity(i);
                                            finish();
                                     }
                              }
                       });
          th.start(); // start the thread
   }
```

http://www.codehubb.com/android_splash_screen

Answer (score 0):

I have added splash screen by using following code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
        initConstatnts();// method for intilizing any constants

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (!isFinishing()) // checking activity is finishing or not
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);//delay

                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }).start();

    }

    private void initConstatnts() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flow the below steps to Create your own splash screen**

1. Create Activity1 and XML file
2. Design the XML file and put the welcome message
3. Crete Activity2 and XML file.
4. Start the Activity1
5. Start a Thread in Activity1 and sleep for 5 seconds
6. Start Activity2 from the Thread

There is nothing called readymade splash screen in Android . we can achieve that using above steps.

In a single line, start Activity1 wait for 5 sec then start Activity2.

So user will feel that first screen is splash screen.

You can download the complete code from below link

http://javaant.com/splash-screen-android/#.VwzHz5N96Hs

Answer (score -3):

i have faced the same problem.... i think you code is perfect for the app

u just try with this in the Intent Creation in your splash activity class

Intent openMainActivity =  new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");//MAIN is the that u want to start
                                                                    //next after the current Activity