# Start new activity when splash screen finished

Tags: android, splash-screen

I've an app.
When my app start, I show and splash screen. When my splash screen finish, I start my main activity.
But I've a problem. When I rotate my app in splash screen, my app restart and four senconds later, start my new activity. If I rotate my splash screen three time, start three main activity.

I want start only one activity, how I can do it?

This is my splash screen code:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

public static final int seconds=4;
public static final int miliseconds=seconds*1000;

private ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    progressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(seconds-1);
    progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    startAnimation();
}

public void startAnimation(){
    new CountDownTimer(miliseconds,1000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //progressbar update--->1 second
            progressBar.setProgress(getMiliseconds(millisUntilFinished));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            Splash.this.startActivityForResult(i,1);
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //when I return to the MainActivity, finish my app
    if(requestCode==1) finish();
}

public int getMiliseconds(long milis){
    return (int) ((milisegundos-milis)/1000);
}
```

}

Comment: See this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279077/android-splash-screen-to-activity

Comment: Changing phone's rotation re-creates your activity oncreate will be called again.

Comment: Refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android) link.

Answer (score 1):

Use `configchanges` in your activity tag in manifest.xml

**Example**

```
<activity
     android:name=".Splash"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

you can use this tag on another activities as well if you want to avoid onCreate again and again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent i =  new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, you need to set the orientation to a specific orientation. Add in `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` under the stuff for your activity. For example, my activity might look like this now:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreen"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you are in landscape mode, use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.

**If this doesn't work**, in your `onFinish()` method, use the following:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```